# How can I pass a function with custom information?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, socket.io, undefined

I'm working with node.js (socket.io)
And it would be great to have *socket.on()* use a unique callback function for every client that joins.

My current approach :

I have a very basic javascript class (containing a function and variable) :

```
function MyClass () {
    this.theIndex = 7;
    this.myFunction= function (){
    console.log("theIndex : " + this.theIndex);
    };
}
```

And the instance of it :

```
var myInstance = new MyClass ();
```

My problem is that when I pass it as a parameter, it logs "**theIndex : undefined**".

```
socket.on('disconnect', myInstance.myFunction);
```

So I'm guessing that once I've passed the function, it loses reference to the class it is in.

Why is it so?
How can I have a function contain custom information?

Comment: because functions are object in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript the `this` is defined based on the invocation context.
In your case you are passing the function, which is nothing but a property of MyClass. When the function gets executed the `this` gets changed based on how you invoke it.

If you want to keep reference of the class then use bind e.g `socket.on('disconnect', myInstance.myFunction.bind(myInstance));`